# Jquery error sending hex code through get

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, colors, get

here is my code below...

```
var o_color ='<?php echo $o_color;?>'; //i have also tried urlencode($o_color)
var o_color1 ='';
```

This code works fine....

```
   window.location.href = site+"name="+$(this).attr('id')+'&o_color='+o_color;
```

but this code does not work....

```
   window.location.href = site+"name="+$(this).attr('id')+'&o_color='+o_color+'&o_color1='+o_color1;

Note:o_color is in hexa code #e34343;
```

i get an jquery error message on console log...

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[rel=123123&o_color1=]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove double quotes from `"o_color"`

```
window.location.href = site+"name="+$(this).attr('id')+'&o_color='+ o_color +'&o_color1='+o_color1;
```

accroding you must be:-

```
<script>
var site='http://localhost/new/';
var o_color = '#e34343';
var o_color1 = '';
window.location.href = site+'name=dfg&o_color='+o_color+'&o_color1='+o_color1;
</script>
```

Comment: Iam sorry i just updated the correct code.. where i have already tried removing the "" quotes... i was testing by inserting "" ,,i updated that code by mistake.... ...both the code not working....

Comment: Try to use only quotes `'` or double quotes `"` to wrap your query string. Currently you're mixing both of it. Also, are you sure that the syntax error happen at above line?

Comment: just now i tried `window.location.href = site+'?font_name='+$(this).attr('id')+'&o_color='+ o_color +'&o_color1='+o_color1;`  on the addressbar i see `www.example.com?font_name=Alpha_Mack&o_color=#e30456&o_color1=` but on cosole  error i see `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[rel=e30456&o_color1=] ` :(

Comment: So the `url` is correct? The error is probably coming from other line IMO

Comment: Yup even i feel the same... let me update my question with other page code,,,

Comment: Yup got it... it was not fetching data from an other url... its fine now....sorry did not purposly downvoted... anyways...upvoted now... Thanks @felix and Rakesh

Answer (score 2):

try

```
window.location.href = site+"name="+$(this).attr('id')+"&o_color="+o_color+"&o_color1="+o_color1;
```

according you

```
<script>
var site='http://localhost/new/';
var o_color = '#e34343';
var o_color1 = '';
window.location.href = site+'name=dfg&o_color='+o_color+'&o_color1='+o_color1;
</script>
```

Comment: Iam sorry i just updated the correct code.. where i have already tried removing the "" quotes... i was testing by inserting "" ,,i updated that code by mistake....

Comment: as I got the clear response from felix "So the url is correct? The error is probably coming from other line IMO – Felix" i have accepted his answer.. anyways thanks alot for trying i have upvoted your answer.. :)